# Creating an Eclipse RCP application and plugin repository from the same sources

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm trying to create an Eclipse (3.x) RCP application from plugins in such a way as to allow me to provide ordinary plugins for existing Eclipse installations, but also create an RCP application from those plugins.

My experimentation has led me to have the following layout:

- `com.company.testapp.plugin`
- `com.company.testapp.feature`
- `com.company.testapp.updatesite`

Where each ID depends on the previous one. This works correctly and I can build an update site from the plugin via the feature. What I would now like to do is add something like

- `com.company.testapp.rcp`

Containing just the required machinery to provide an RCP 'wrapper' around the feature. `com.company.testapp.rcp` contains a product definition, `testapp.product`.

However, I can't seem to make this link work; I'm getting "Product `com.company.testapp.rcp.product` could not be found" on trying to launch from the product configuration.

(Ultimately, I'd like to be able to drive the creation of both the update site and RCP application from Maven/Tycho—I have another `com.company.testapp.master` containing the master POM which I can again successfully build the update site from.)

I've found plenty of resources on building plugins with Tycho, and plenty on building RCP applications, but nothing on building both from the same source tree. I'm not an Eclipse or Tycho expert by any means, so it's possible I'm just not aware of what I should be searching for.

Is such a thing even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `com.company.testapp.updatesite` (and `com.company.testapp.rcp`) create a new module: `com.company.testapp.repository` that defines a product and p2 repository (a replacement for old update-site mechanism). The module should have the following files:

- `category.xml` where you define features in p2 repository and their categories (in your case `com.company.testapp.feature`)
- `*.product` - a product definition file
- `pom.xml` file that defines `eclipse-repository` module; detailed configuration is explained at [Tycho Packaging Types - eclipse-repository](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types#eclipse-repository)